# CSS nth-child is not working based on my expectation

Tags: html, css

I have following HTML code

```
<div class="our-services">
    <h1 class="center-text">Our Services</h1>
    <div class="service-box">
        <h3 class="center-text">Service 1</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="service-box">
        <h3 class="center-text">Service 2</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="service-box">
        <h3 class="center-text">Service 3</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non.</p>
    </div>          
</div>
```

and there is a class called **service-box** which I used 3 times. Now I want margin-right should be zero to the 3rd service-box class. So for that I am using following CSS code:

```
.service-box:nth-child(4) {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

and It working fine.

but my question is why the nth value is 4 instead of 3? If I use 3 then it's not working, why?

**Update: (It's not duplicate Question)**

My question was why I need to use 4 instead of 3. As I saw an example here: https://www.w3schools.com/csSref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_nth-child

In this link, you can see that if you want to select the second p element then you need to use p:nth-child(2), right? So then why my code is not accepting 3?

Comment: My code is working but I wan to know why it's working using 4 instead of 3.

Comment: True. I tried it in a fiddle. This is indeed very strange behavior. Maybe add a fiddle to your post??

Comment: @TVBZ ' indeed very strange behavior ' ? No. This is the intended behavior. See answers below. Also, why so many upvotes on this question that already has a lot of answers here on SO and online + the docs are very clear about nth-child works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because the first `service-box` is actually the second child of its parent, `center-text` being the first. Remove `center-text` and use `.service-box:nth-child(3)`.

```css
.service-box:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="our-services">
  <div class="service-box">
    <h3 class="center-text">Service 1</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="service-box">
    <h3 class="center-text">Service 2</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="service-box">
    <h3 class="center-text">Service 3</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

if you want, you can use `nth-of-type`, which is more specific

```css
.service-box:nth-of-type(3) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="our-services">
  <h1 class="center-text">Our Services</h1>
  <div class="service-box">
    <h3 class="center-text">Service 1</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="service-box">
    <h3 class="center-text">Service 2</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="service-box">
    <h3 class="center-text">Service 3</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

More info [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-child/#points-of-interest)

Comment: LOVE you so much :) I understand :)

Answer (score 4):

The `nth-child` selector is not an `nth-class` selector. So it doesn't select depending on class or other attributes. It selects the nth element which is in a list of children.

In this case you need to add `(4)` not `(3)` because you have `<h1 class="center-text">` which is a sibling of your `service-box`. So all service-box + h1 are children of the same parent.

Docs are very clear

[w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp) [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)

> The :nth-child(n) selector matches every element that is the nth child, regardless of type, of its parent.
>
> The :nth-child() CSS pseudo-class matches elements based on their position in a group of siblings.

Take this example

```css
.my-child:nth-child(3) {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div>
 <span>First child</span>
 <p> Second Child </p>
 <h2 class="my-child"> THird Child</h2>
</div>
```

so to select the `my-child` with the `nth-child` selector, you need to add (3) because even if it's a different element than the others and has a specific class, it's the 3rd child inside the parent element.

That being said, there is NO nth-class selector.
In your specific case, you can use the `nth-of-type(n)` selector. Which selects the type of the element. And because `service-box` are `div` elements, and the only other sibling is a `h1` element. Using **`nth-of-type(3)`** will select your 3rd `section-box`.

But if you want to select the last child and not a specific one, you can use `:last-child`

```css
.service-box:nth-of-type(3) {
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="our-services">
    <h1 class="center-text">Our Services</h1>
    <div class="service-box">
        <h3 class="center-text">Service 1</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="service-box">
        <h3 class="center-text">Service 2</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="service-box">
        <h3 class="center-text">Service 3</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non.</p>
    </div>          
</div>
```